# return array of data from from server to vb.net

Tags: .net, winforms

I need to return an array of data securely from my webserver to my vb.net application in this format, something like an update that has to be done regularly.

name1, age1, sex1, location1

name2, age2, sex2, location2

name3, age3, sex3, location3

.....

so what is the best way to get this data so that i can easily process it from my vb.net application

[EDIT]

I forgot to mention that my website is developed in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Web Service or an Application Service.  See here for full info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx

There's a LOT of info there but actually, it's VERY simple to set up a web service and consume it from .NET.

The videos here may serve as a gentler introduction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784

And another good video can be found here: http://www.asp.net/general/videos/an-introduction-to-soap-based-web-services-with-visual-web-developer-2008 - This one is more of an introduciton but really, it should be about all you need.